# Java Eclipse Kepler error on startup on OS X machine

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I did a clean install of OS X, now the installation of Eclipse Kepler won't work. On startup I get an error (before eclipse asks me what workspace to use). The error includes: 
`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage (file:/Users/jodeneve/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.0.v20130529-1710.jar) to method java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release`

Opening the log file I see that it uses java 9.0. (not what I want) I believe for it to work it needs to use an older version of java. Therefor I installed older versions and I use `jenv` to switch between them. e.g. `jenv global 1.6` which changes the global java version used to 1.6, I check this using java -version. However opening eclipse still results in a log file saying it used java version 9. Any clues?

I need Kepler because I want to use plug in only available (or working) on Kepler or older eclipse versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the eclipse.ini file to point to the 1.6 path.  Should look like this in the file:

```
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.6\bin\javaw.exe
```

More information on the eclipse.ini file can be found here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: okay I added an eclipse.ini file:

-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java/
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m

However in the log it still denotes java 9

Comment: to be clear, I adapted the existing one .. but still in the log it says java 9

Comment: Did you read the eclipse.ini wiki page very carefully? Of particular note is the fact that `-vm` and the path must be on separate lines. Also compare yours to the OS X example: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Mac_OS_X_Example

Comment: Hello I was able to solve it, I used java 8 in the eclipse.ini and it finally opens using the command line. Opening the program directly results in a crash with little to no explanation "program crashed reopen, close"